# Advice on how my services should be interacting

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, soa

I have a account registration page, and I have the following service classes:

1. userService
2. roleService
3. emailService

So when the user registers, I have to:

1. create a user in the db
2. add the user to a specific role
3. email the user

I'm using spring MVC, so this has to be done in the registration method.

Now, my question is, should I do inject/use the other services from WITHIN the userService's register method?

```
userService.register(....)

public class UserServiceImpl ... {

   public void register(....) {

      save(user);
      roleService.associateTo(....);
      emailService.sendRegistrationEmail(...);
   }
}
```

OR

Is that making things too coupled, I should make these calls seperately in the controllers method like:

```
public ModelAndView register(..., HttpServletRequest request, ...) {

    ..

    userService.register(user);
    roleService.associateTo(...);
    emailService.sendRegistrationEmail(...);

}
```

I'm sort of leaning towards the 2nd approach.  Say i wanted to create or register users in a bulk way, calling register would be doing so many things that I would maybe not want to do since I'm doing it in a bulk manner  (this is just something I thought of, maybe its a edge case?)

Answer (score 3):

I would add third solution to the mix:

```
public class UserRegistrationService ... {

    public void register(....) {
        userService.save(user);
        roleService.associateTo(....);
        emailService.sendRegistrationEmail(...);
    }

    public void registerInBatch(...) {
        foreach(...) {
            userService.save(user);
            roleService.associateTo(....);
        }
    }
}
```

Performing several steps in a controller is a poor idea in terms of reusing the code. If you want to expose the same logic via REST or any other interface you will either end up trying to call a controller directly or copying all the steps to another place. C&P development is a terrible thing - next time you want to add a step to registration process you'll need to add it in all places.

Eventually you will come up with a service wrapping all steps in a single method like in your first solution or in mine suggested above.

Comment: your solution is interesting, but it still is making me code 2 different methods...but I guess the situation warrants that.

Comment: one more thing, would you add this service (UserRegistrationService) in the same folder as your other services, or should I create a folder like 'aggregated services' which wrap other services? just want your advice that's all...

Comment: @Blankman: it's up to you. I would place both `UserService` and `UserRegistrationService` in the same package, on the other hand they represent different levels of abstraction...

Answer (score 2):

I'd add a fourth; create a user registration event and listen for it.

I'd remove the email send from the mainline code altogether at the very least and handle that as either a message on a queue, or at least an asynch event to avoid any potential latency issues.

(I'd also probably do something with users so you can create a user with a role in a single operation just for convenience, but that's a different issue, and arguable either way.)

Comment: The email service actually writes to a queue, so it is just writing the message to the queue not sending it out.